# primefaces selectOneMenu value using Selenium Webdriver+Java

Tags: xpath, jsf-2, selenium, primefaces

I need to set value to primefaces or JSF selectOneMenu using webdriver.

I am able to achieve this using index but could not set value directly.

The following code is working with Index:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("LNSYNDGLP0_SL_CCY_editableInput")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='LNSYNDGLP0_SL_CCY_panel']/ul/li[7]")).click();
```

Could anybody please suggest a way to achieve setting value to selectonemenu using Selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `[text()='item value']` selector in XPath to select the element by its node value.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='LNSYNDGLP0_SL_CCY_panel']/ul/li[text()='item value']")).click();
```

Comment: Great! I found that the xpath needed a little tweaking so in my case it was: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LNSYNDGLP0_SL_CCY_panel']/div/ul/li[text()='item value']")).click();`